# Difference between `socket.close()` and `socket.fromfd()` for closing a file descriptor associated with a socket?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, macos, network-programming, python-3.7

Consider the underlying file descriptor `fd` of a `socket`.

I experience the following issue, using `socket.close(fd)` (Python 3.7) to close `fd` on client disconnect. When the client reconnects, and the OS allocates a same-numbered `fd`, and error is thrown when attempting to read from `fd`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poll.py", line 37, in <module>
    buf = os.read(fd, 4096)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

If I instead closes `fd` by the following code, then everything just works, and it is possible to read from newly-created and same-numbered `fd`:

```
c = socket.fromfd(fd, socket.AF_INET, socket_SOCK_STREAM)
c.close()
```

Can someone explain this behavior? Isn't `socket.closefd(fd)` introduced in Python 3.7 as "syntatic sugar" for the above code?